# Convert a list of strings to a list of strings and ints

Tags: python-3.x

I have a dictionary of lists, each list has 3 elements, i want to convert the 2nd and 3rd element to ints from strings

```py
dict = {1:['string', '2', '3',],
        2:['string', '2', '3',],
        3:['string', '2', '3',],}
```

to become:

```
dict = {1:['string', 2, 3,],
        2:['string', 2, 3,],
        3:['string', 2, 3,],}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, don't name your dictionaries **dict**, as it's a reserved keyword and you don't wanna overwrite it.

Coming to your solution.

```py
d = {
    1: ['string', '23', '3'],
    2: ['string', '2', '3'],
    3: ['string', '2', '3'],
}


d2 = {
    k: [
        int(i) if i.isdigit() else i 
        for i in v
    ] 
    for k, v in d.items()
}
```

Will give you an output of:

```
{   
    1: ['string', '23', '3'], 
    2: ['string', '2', '3'], 
    3: ['string', '2', '3']
}
{
    1: ['string', 23, 3], 
    2: ['string', 2, 3], 
    3: ['string', 2, 3]
}
```

Comment: **Caution**: This solution will also convert the *first* element of the list to an integer when it contains only digits! This was not requested by OP

Answer (score 0):

If you dictionary has many elements you might not want to create a second dictionary in memory, but modify the existing one in-place:

```
data = {
    1: ['string', '2', '3'],
    2: ['string', '2', '3'],
    3: ['string', '2', '3'],
}

for v in data.values():
    v.append(int(v.pop(1)))
    v.append(int(v.pop(1)))

print(data)
```

**Output:**

```
{1: ['string', 2, 3], 2: ['string', 2, 3], 3: ['string', 2, 3]}
```